# Discrepancy between generated Julia set and Wikipedia image

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, html5-canvas, fractals

I have written a small javascript program to view julia set images [[link]](http://thejamespaterson.com/scripts/julia/). I've ben implementing multiple iteration algorithms (Not just `z^2 + c`) and recently implemented `exp(z)`. However, my output differs from the wikipedia page image. Here's a comparison for the c value `-0.65`:

My image: 
[image: My julia set]

Wikipedia image[image]

Obviously, their output is a lot more colourful and shows a lot more detail! I was thinking it is probably a mistake in my implementation, or maybe my coloring algorithm? Or is the wikipedia result generated by some differing means? Below is an MVE with just the `e^z + c` algorithm and the relevant functions. If you want to play with the whole program feel free, it's hosted [on my site](http://thejamespaterson.com/scripts/julia/).

```js
//globals
var MAXITERATION = 2500;
var BOUNDARY = 4;
var CANVASID = "juliaDraw";
var CANVAS = document.getElementById("juliaDraw");
var CONTEXT = document.getElementById("juliaDraw").getContext('2d');
var HEIGHT = 750;
var WIDTH = 750;
var CONVERGENCEITERCOUNT = 2500;

/** Complex number functions **/

function complexNum(real, imaginary) {
  this.real = real;
  this.imaginary = imaginary;
  return this;
}

// This is the bit that might be a problem but it seems to return correct results? 
function raiseNumberToComplexPower(x, c) {
  var s = Math.pow(x, c.real);
  var pow = c.imaginary * Math.log(x);
  var num = new complexNum(Math.cos(pow), Math.sin(pow));
  return scalarComplex(s, num);
}

function addComplex(c1, c2) {
  var real = c1.real + c2.real;
  var imaginary = c1.imaginary + c2.imaginary;
  return new complexNum(real, imaginary);
}

function multComplex(c1, c2) {
  var real = (c1.real * c2.real) - (c1.imaginary * c2.imaginary);
  var imaginary = (c1.real * c2.imaginary) + (c2.real * c1.imaginary);
  return new complexNum(real, imaginary);
}

function scalarComplex(s, c) {
  return new complexNum(c.real * s, c.imaginary * s);
}

function getComplexModulus(c) {
 return Math.sqrt((c.real * c.real) + (c.imaginary * c.imaginary));
}

/** Drawing and manipulation **/

function createArray(length) {
  var arr = new Array(length || 0),
    i = length;
  if (arguments.length > 1) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    while (i--) arr[length - 1 - i] = createArray.apply(this, args);
  }
  return arr;
}

function drawJulia() {
  CONTEXT.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  var start = new complexNum(-2, 2);
  var c = new complexNum(readInput('realValue') * 1, readInput('imagValue') * 1);
  STARTPOS = {
    real: -2,
    imaginary: 2
  }
  RANGE = 4;
  plotJuliaSet(CANVASID, c);
}

function plotJuliaSet(canvasID, c) {
  var complexNumberArray = createArray(WIDTH + 1, HEIGHT + 1);
  var doesPointEscapeArray = createArray(WIDTH + 1, HEIGHT + 1);
  ITERALGO = exponential;
  for (var x = 0; x <= WIDTH; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y <= HEIGHT; y++) {
      complexNumberArray[x][y] = new coordsToComplex({
        x: x,
        y: y
      });
      complexNumberArray[x][y] = complexNumberArray[x][y];
      doesPointEscapeArray[x][y] = doesPointEscape(c, complexNumberArray[x][y]);
      if (doesPointEscapeArray[x][y] >= 0) {
        drawPointOnCanvas(x, y, getColor(doesPointEscapeArray[x][y]));
      } else {
        drawPointOnCanvas(x, y, 'black');
      }
    }
  }
  console.log('done');
}

function doesPointEscape(c, complexNum) {
  var iterations = 0;
  var iterationsToEscape = -1;
  var escaped = false;
  while ((!escaped) && (iterations < MAXITERATION)) {
    if (getComplexModulus(complexNum) > BOUNDARY) {
      escaped = true;
      iterationsToEscape = iterations;
    }
    complexNum = ITERALGO(complexNum, c);
    iterations++;
  }
  return iterationsToEscape;
}

function exponential(complexNum, c) {
  // e^z + c
  return addComplex(raiseNumberToComplexPower(Math.E, complexNum), c);
}

function drawPointOnCanvas(x, y, color) {
  CONTEXT.fillStyle = color;
  CONTEXT.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
}

function getColor(iterations) {
  //console.log("Iterations: "+getBaseLog(iterations+1,255));
  var color = "rgb(" + Math.floor((8 * iterations) % 255) + "," + Math.floor(2 * iterations % 255) + "," + Math.floor(255 - ((8 * iterations) % 255)) + ")";
  //console.log(color);
  return color;
}

function coordsToComplex(coordinates) {
  return {
    real: ((coordinates.x / WIDTH) * RANGE + STARTPOS.real),
    imaginary: ((coordinates.y / HEIGHT) * -RANGE + STARTPOS.imaginary)
  };
}

function complexToCoords(c) {
  return {
    x: ((c.real - STARTPOS.real) / (RANGE)) * WIDTH,
    y: ((c.imaginary - STARTPOS.imaginary) / -(RANGE)) * HEIGHT
  };
}

function readInput(inputID) {
  return document.getElementById(inputID).value;
}
```

```css
.desc {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
}
#juliaDraw {
  border: 1px dotted;
  float: left;
}
.canvasWrapper canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="desc">
  <h1>Julia Set Viewer</h1> 
  <form>
    <label>Real:
      <input type="text" id="realValue" value="-0.65">
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>Imag:
      <input type="text" id="imagValue" value="0">
    </label>
    <input type="button" onClick="drawJulia()" value="Draw">
  </form>
</div>
<canvas id="juliaDraw" width=750 height=750 onClick="drawZoomJulia()"></canvas>
```

Comment: What is the thinking behind your `getColor()` function?

Comment: I need to condense an extremely large amount of iterations,  and integer, into an rgb colour 3-tuple. As rgb is 0-255, it makes sense to take iterations modulo 255. The different multipliers are to give a range of colours - using the same multipliers gives a simple gradient around one colour which isn't very fun. I also inverted the blue channel to start at 255 so that the iteration would start at blue and then proceed to red, then cycle betweena them. If you go to my site , and use the right click zoom you can see the colours generated better.

Comment: Well, the number of iterations won't ever exceed 2500, right? The RGB color space covers (nominally) 16 million values. So I don't see how the word "condense" is relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: which wikipedia page ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(discrete_dynamical_systems)

Comment: https://sk.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juliova_mno%C5%BEina

Comment: I believe the equivalent section was taken out of the English Wikipedia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is really a mathematical one. Specifically, you're using an escape criterion built for polynomials on an exponential function. In all cases, it appears that you iterate until the iterate exceeds `BOUNDARY` in absolute value and `BOUNDARY` is set to 4 at the outset. The Wikepedia image evidently uses a much larger escape value. In the following two images, we compare an escape radius of 4 with an escape radius of 100; the larger escape radius is much more like the Wikipedia image:

[image]

But, frankly, the Wikipedia image is incorrect as well. The whole point behind Julia set pictures is to attempt to decompose the complex plane into two sets: one set where the dynamics are simple and another set where the dynamics are complicated. We iterate a polynomial until the absolute value is large because *all* points with large absolute value will escape to infinity. That's not true for your function `exp(z)-0.65`. For example, if `z=-100`, then `abs(z)` is fairly large but `exp(-100)-0.65` is very close to `-0.65`. There's no good escape criterion in terms of the absolute value for exponential functions.

What *does* work well is to iterate your function until it's *real* part is large. It's like there's an escape to the right side of the complex plane. If we iterate your function until the real part exceeds 100 we get something like so:

[image]

Comment: Which Wikepedia image ?